# Custom Token Service for issuing and validating JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

We need to develop a "single sign on" service (SSO) to issue JWT for numerous amount of clients. Developers of these clients will also need an ability to validate these tokens. Obviously we can't provide them with our secret key we used to generate these tokens. So instead we decided to provide them an API service with two methods. One for issuing token and the second one to validate it.

I'm questioning myself if we're going for the right approach. Here is a basic scheme which shows how users will be working with their clients (secure applications)

[image: Fig. 1 - Basic scheme of users interactions]

User signs on with his credentials via our service and gets his access token. 
Then his token is used in request headers of the secure application. SSO client module is AuthenticationHandler which sends HTTP requests to our service to check validity of the token.

Here is some code from SSO client module we use to validate the token. We use custom authentication handler which makes calls to the remote SSO service:

```
internal class SsoAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<SsoAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!TryRetrieveToken(Request, out var token))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }

        if (await _ssoClient.ValidateTokenAsync(token))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(...);
        }

        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
    }
}
```

and the SsoClient iself:

```
public class SsoClient
{
    public async Task<bool> ValidateTokenAsync(string token)
    {
        const string validateUrl = "api/auth/validatetoken";

        var address = $"https://{_ssoHost}/{validateUrl}";
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            var res = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(address));
            reply = DeserializeSsoReply(res);
        }

        return reply.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find what would be best practices for our scenario so I wonder if there are any possible pitfalls we can encounter with this approach?

Comment: From my personal experience, I strongly recommend to use implementations provided by asp.net core and / or IdentityServer4. Writing all these stuff in a correct and secure way is not so easy. Imo the "best practice" here is: "do not reinvent the wheel".

Answer (score 0):

When we had a similar situation what we did was for each valid client they had a certificate they could use to create JWTs for the destination (aka us) service.  After validating at their origin, their credentials were repackaged and resigned using the certificate we shared with them.  For a limited number of valid callers this helped us keep track of the true origin (based on the signing cert) as well as having a standardized payload for our use.

On receipt we validate that the audience is correct (aka us) and that signer is one of the configured signers.

Everyone keeps their own secrets and anyone you want to believe that you are you, you provide your public key.  The owner of the key (aka you) always controls your secret but everyone has to agree on the end to end protocol.

I don't consider this reinventing so much as securing the popular path and limiting entry to a know set of users.